# pyhton tkinter append list

Tags: python, tkinter

> I have written a bit of code, but my problem is it puts **<tkinter.Entry object .!entry>** every time I press the "add words" button. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

```
import tkinter as tk

balls = tk.Tk()
CensoredList=[]

window1 = tk.Canvas(balls, width = 400, height = 300)
window1.pack()

title = tk.Label(balls, text="Bad Word Blocker")
title.config(font=("Bahnschrift", 14))
window1.create_window(200, 25, window=title)

subtitle = tk.Label(balls, text="Enter a word or phrase you 
would like blocked:")
subtitle.config(font=("Bahnschrift", 10))
window1.create_window(200, 100, window=subtitle)

entry = tk.Entry(balls) 
window1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry)

def fobblejibbits():
    CensoredList.append(entry)

def heebyjeeby():
    print(CensoredList)

pressme = tk.Button(balls, text ="add word to list", command = 
fobblejibbits)
pressme.pack()

pressme2 = tk.Button(balls, text ="are you done adding words", 
command = heebyjeeby)
pressme2.pack()

balls.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have to use `get()` method on the entries to get the value inside of it

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add in a variable to associate as text with the entry field.  Following is a code snippet that does that.

```
import tkinter as tk

balls = tk.Tk()
CensoredList=[]

name_var=tk.StringVar() # Add this

window1 = tk.Canvas(balls, width = 400, height = 300)
window1.pack()

title = tk.Label(balls, text="Bad Word Blocker")
title.config(font=("Bahnschrift", 14))
window1.create_window(200, 25, window=title)

subtitle = tk.Label(balls, text="Enter a word or phrase you would like blocked:")
subtitle.config(font=("Bahnschrift", 10))
window1.create_window(200, 100, window=subtitle)

entry = tk.Entry(balls, textvariable = name_var)    # Note the use of the string variable here
window1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry)

def fobblejibbits():
    name=name_var.get()         # Add this
    CensoredList.append(name)
    name_var.set("")            # Clear the field

def heebyjeeby():
    print(CensoredList)

pressme = tk.Button(balls, text ="add word to list", command = fobblejibbits)
pressme.pack()

pressme2 = tk.Button(balls, text ="are you done adding words", command = heebyjeeby)
pressme2.pack()

balls.mainloop()
```

The field added is the string variable "name_var".

When I tested out the program, I pumped out a list to the terminal.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Censored$ python3 Censored.py 
['Hello', 'Goodbye']
```

Give that a try.